# PHP: Getting recipient id

Tags: php, mysql

Hey, so I have a recipient field in my form you can type a user´s fullname in, example "john derek".

Now i have exploded this into $firstname and $lastname

```
list($firstname, $lastname) = array_map('ucfirst', explode(' ', $recipient, 2));
```

How can i check in the database if there's any full match, take the id.

table users has column "firstname" and "lastname"

If theres half match, if only there exists firstname (john) or lastname(derek) and not both, echo "Did you mean: John Derek?";

```
$qur = mysql_query('
 SELECT id, firstname, lastname, 
 (firstname = "$firstname" AND lastname = "$lastname") AS full FROM users 
 WHERE (firstname = "$firstname" AND lastname="$lastname") 
 OR (firstname LIKE "$firstname%" AND lastname LIKE "$lastname%")
 ORDER BY (firstname = "$firstname" AND lastname="$lastname") DESC');
 $get = mysql_fetch_array($qur);
 echo $get["full"] ."<br>";
```

Im not getting anything in this, even that $firstname is "John" and $lastname is "Derek"

also tried:

```
echo $get["id"];
echo $get["lastname"]
echo $get["firstname"]
```

Seems like it dont find anything? What is wrong?

Comment: What if you have a recipient with three or more names? Either way, I think you should add more detail. Is there a ready-made recipient list that the user can only look up in? Or how does the "did you mean" mechanism come into play? What does your database table look like? Would a LIKE search that finds "John Derek" when the user enters "John D" also be feasible, or do you need to match firstname and lastname separately?

Comment: lets say the recipient doesnt.

Comment: At the recipientfield, I have an autosuggest, so you dont have to write full name.  The echo "Did you mean" is just for me, to edit later, as I would like to ask the user if he ment this name (show full name)- if it wasnt full match.

Comment: @Johnson but where do the auto-suggestions come from? Is there an existing list of recipients? What does your database structure look like?

Comment: If you enter "John Der" it should firstly check if there's any full match On John Der, if not check for John and LIKE 'Der' in lastname, if yes show Did you mean John derek?

Comment: @Pekka yes from the database, there's a table users with columns id, firstname, lastname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to do a LIKE query:

```
 SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM users 
 WHERE firstname LIKE "$firstname%"
 AND lastname LIKE "$lastname%"
```

(Don't forget sanitizing the variables, of course)

User input that this would match:

```
Jo De
J Derek
John D
```

It would give you a result set back. If, for a search for `John Der`, there is a `John Derek` and a `John Der` though, there's no guarantee that `John Der` will come first. To achieve that, you'd have to check for literal matches first:

```
 SELECT id, firstname, lastname, 
 (firstname = "$firstname" AND lastname="$lastname") AS full FROM users 
 WHERE (firstname = "$firstname" AND lastname="$lastname") 
 OR (firstname LIKE "$firstname%" AND lastname LIKE "$lastname%")
 ORDER BY (firstname = "$firstname" AND lastname="$lastname") DESC
```

this will give the full match first, partial matches second.

It may need further tweaking, but it should be a start.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. how can i echo if full match on what you wrote, and if not then "did you mean john derek"

Comment: @Johnson I updated the second, big query. It will give you a fourth, virtual column in the result named "full". It will be "1" or "TRUE" (not sure right now, you'd have to test it) if it's a full match.

Comment: @Johnson note though that the full match will match only if the case matches too ("John Derek" instead of "jon derek"). If you want this more lenient, you need to `strtolower()` the term in PHP, and wrap a `LCASE()` around the field names in the SQL statement

Comment: @Johnson that is a string problem, has nothing to do with the query. If you use a IDE, the syntax highlighting should show you where the problem is (it's usually something trivial like a forgotten quote). Otherwise, open a new question

Comment: I have your code in $qur = mysql_query("..."); and im getting this, when i remove the $qur im getting no error.-- Im using notepad++

Comment: Ok found it, i made mysql_query("") and not mysql_query(''), now I dont receive the error. I have fetch_array the query, and when i try to  echo $get["full"] ; Im not getting any results? Could you help me tell how I should use the query?

Comment: @Johnson ah, okay. This is because strings wrapped in `'` quotes won't interpret the variables in there. Reverse the order: Wrap the query in `"` and use `'` in the SQL. Partly my mistake, sorry